# Can a 5mW laser diode's output be doubled for a short time (5s)?

Tags: thermal, laser-diode

Friends are using the [KY-008 laser transmitter module](https://arduinomodules.info/ky-008-laser-transmitter-module/) for a sensing/computer vision project prototype.

They are having issues with insufficient laser dot brightness when their target is lit by direct sunlight. It's marginally visible by their CV at that level of background illumination.
They suspect that increasing the laser brightness by some 200-300% (and with the necessary precautions) may solve their issues.

I've seen the module they are using, it is either a KY-008 or a close copy. It's just the laser LED can + a 100-ohm series resistor, as it is made 5V Arduino-compatible.

I've been unable to locate a datasheet of the laser LED exactly, but [this one](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/348/rld65mzt700a009-e-1843566.pdf) is a very close match. Indeed, it says Iop = 28mA, which is exactly what I'm measuring when I feed 5V to the module (and the 100-ohm resistor is also sized to this). I assume this is for 5mW output power.

Now, the datasheet also says these:

- **Absolute maximum rating: output power**: 7mW
- ...
- **Operating current**: typ 28mA, max 70mA

The first one suggests only a modest allowance for brightness increase, while the second one allows for more than double.

Nether suggests any thermal timing constraints. My friends only need the laser lit for ~5s, and they can allow for much more time for it to cool afterwards before it's used again.

## Question

Which constraint in the datasheet is more applicable to the 5s usage time scenario? The 7mW one? Or the 70mA one?

(I can of course "just try and see if it burns out". But if there's some long-term degradation caused by the elevated current, I'll likely not notice)

Comment: Rather than try to outshine the sun  consider filtering it. SCHOTT RG610 long pass filter will improve your signal to background ratio dramatically. 30 dollars from Edmunds, less then ten on eBay.

Comment: I don't think it means anything that you found an datasheet that looks like a close match because TO-56 cases all look the same. 5s is also an eternity for a semiconductor and laser diodes are notoriously sensitive to overcurrent. 7mW is the OPTICAL output.

Comment: anrieff, You need to distinguish the laser light from sunlight. You do ***not*** do this by upping the power. That's a losing strategy and brutish, at best. You do this by modifying the laser beam so that it distinguishes itself and then take advantage of that modification on the receiving end. You'll be way ahead of the game, then. There are ***many*** ideas available but a suggestion is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_angular_momentum_of_light). It's easy to create  using a laser through a spatial filter (little holes in a specific pattern on a sheet.) Talk with a specialist.

Comment: anrieff, I actually was able to find a [nice quick sheet](https://technology.nasa.gov/patent/LAR-TOPS-306) at a page at NASA. At the bottom there is a link to a summary PDF. That's the basic idea. It's really cool because it can direct your laser source "elsewhere" than where the sunlight goes and thus avoid saturating your detector.

Comment: Also sunlight is DC whereas you could modulate your laser and electrically filter the signal from the optically filtered sensor output. A lock-in amplifier might be handy. This optical filter and electronic modulation arrangement is common in TV remote controls to deal with the sunlight problem

Answer (score 2):

Double the power? Probably not when considering that data sheet. Let’s look into the current variation:

[image: current vs power for various temperatures.]

You can see on the plot that a colder laser will achieve 5mW at ~28mA whereas a hot laser needs 50mA for the same output.

Also the KY-008 doesn’t seem to have any feedback control circuit on it, so the output power probably isn’t what it says on the label and would be subject to great variability.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you must not exceed either of the maximum ratings:

- 8mW at 10mA -> not allowed
- 1mW at 71mA -> not allowed

Laser diodes often allow pulsed current higher than the DC rating, though the maximum pulse length and duty cycle will be specified in the datasheet.